# How to handle two one billion record for file comparison

Tags: python, java, unix

I try to read two one billion record files from a Unix server for file comparison.

I tried in python with paramiko package but it is very slow to connect and read the Unix files. That's why I chose Java.
In Java when I read the file I am facing memory issues and performance issues.

My requirement: first read all records from Unix server file1, then read second file records from Unix server and finally compare the two files.

Comment: and you want to do all this with all of file1 in memory?  what are tyou trying to compare? is it line by line? are the files already sorted?

Comment: Removed oracle tab. Not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you want to process huge files. Rule of thumb is they will exceed your RAM so never hope to get them read all at once.

Instead try to read meaningful chunks, process them, then forget them.
Meaningful chunks could be characters, words, lines, expressions, objects.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in UNIX, I would advise you to sort the files and use the `diff` commandline tool: UNIX' commandline commands are quite powerful. Please show us an excerpt of the files (maybe you might need `cut` or `awk` scripts too).